# Requests from the HTML5 AppCache have no referer header set

Tags: html, html5-appcache, offline-caching, cache-manifest

I'm having trouble with the HTML5 AppCache and the requests that it sends, so I wrote a small demonstration of the problem. First, there are two HTML files. One is called `withmanifest.html`, and looks like this:

```
<html manifest="hello.appcache">
<body>
    Hello world
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The second HTML file is called `withoutmanifest.html`, and is completely identical except it omits the manifest attribute. The `client.js` file is just a single line - it doesn't do anything interesting. The `hello.appcache` file caches `client.js`.

I created a simple node.js server (`server.js`) to serve static files in the directory and log the URL and referer header for every request:

```
http = require('http');
nodeStatic = require('node-static');

var staticFileServer = new nodeStatic.Server('./', {cache: 0});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.url + ' ' + (req.headers['referer'] || 'None'));
  req.addListener('end', function() {
    staticFileServer.serve(req, res);
  }).resume();
}).listen(8000);
```

The full code (~50 lines total) is available [on github](https://github.com/josephkaptur/appcache-referer-test).

In Chrome, with no AppCaches set (chrome://appcache-internals is empty), I load `/withoutmanifest.html` and get the following log:

```
/withoutmanifest.html None
/client.js http://localhost:8000/withoutmanifest.html
/favicon.ico None
```

I then load `/withmanifest.html` and get the following log:

```
/withmanifest.html None
/hello.appcache None
/client.js http://localhost:8000/withoutmanifest.html
/client.js None
/withmanifest.html None
/hello.appcache None
```

The second request for `client.js` is sent by the AppCache update process and does not contain a referer header. This is a problem, because what I'm really trying to do is query another server, and that server returns an error if the request doesn't have a referer. I'm not sure what to do next - it seems very strange to me that the AppCache would send a different request from the page itself. Is there any way to set the referer header?

Comment: In my tests the initial appcacheload had the referer set, but after using the applicationCache.update() the next requests have no referer.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=17687